# Finding words that indicate time order using NLP in python

Tags: python, nlp, spacy

I want to find all words that indicate time using NLP in python. Also known as Time-order words in english. This includes works like 'evening' 'morning', 'first', '5 o'clock ', etc. I can't find a way to do this without having to make a list of every time order word in english. I need this for an english to American sign language sentence translator that should convert an English sentence to the correct grammatical structure of an ASL sentence. In ASL, timeorder words should be at the start of the sentence in most cases.

I can't find anything on spaCy or NLTK that does this for me, if anyone knows any functionalities i missed please let me know. This is my current code:

```
import nltk
from nltk.tokenize import sent_tokenize, word_tokenize
import string
import spacy

nltk.download('punkt', )
nltk.download('averaged_perceptron_tagger')

nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')
# nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_lg')  #takess longer to load but is a larger dictionary

sentences=["The big black cat stared at the small dog.",
           "I didn't watch her brother in the evenings.",
           "Which car did Jane buy?"]
doc = nlp(sentences[1])
# for word in doc
tokens_list = []
signs_list = []
for token in doc:
  # remove auxilaries, punctuation, determiners, prepositions
    if token.pos_ not in ['AUX', 'PUNCT'] and token.tag_ not in ['DT','IN']:
        tokens_list.append([token.text, token.lemma_, token.pos_, token.tag_,])
        signs_list.append(token.lemma_)
for sign in signs_list:
  signs_list[signs_list.index(sign)] = sign.lower()
signs_list

if 'not' in signs_list: 
  ind = signs_list.index('not')
  signs_list[ind], signs_list[ind+1] = signs_list[ind+1], signs_list[ind]
# not comes after the verb it negates in ASL

if 'i' in signs_list:
  ind = signs_list.index('i')
  signs_list[ind] = 'me'

# 'me' is used instead of 'i' in ASL

signs_list
```

SOLUTION:

```
timeOrderWords = [synset.lemma_names() for synset in wn.synsets('time_of_day')[0].hyponyms()]
for x in wn.synsets('time_of_day')[0].hyponyms():
  if len(x.hyponyms()) > 0:
    timeOrderwords = [timeOrderWords.append(y.lemma_names()) for y in x.hyponyms()]
timeOrderWords = list(itertools.chain(*timeOrderWords))
timeOrderWords = [timeOrderWords[x].replace('_', " ") for x in range(len(timeOrderWords))]
timeOrderWords = [timeOrderWords[x].replace('-', " ") for x in range(len(timeOrderWords))]
timeOrderWords
```

The code above returns a flat list of all the words related (synsets) to 'time_of_day' and all the hyponyms of those related words. Then all the _ and - are removed from the words

The list looks like this: (I had to add some words myself like afternoon)

```
timeOrderWords = ['aurora', 'afternoon','bedtime', 'break of day', 'break of the day', 'breakfast time','canonical hour','closing time',
 'cockcrow','complin','compline','crepuscle','crepuscule','dawn','dawning','daybreak','dayspring','dinnertime',
 'dusk','early morning hour','evenfall','evening','evensong','fall','first light','gloam','gloaming','happy hour','high noon','late night hour',
 'lights out','lunch period','lunchtime','matins','mealtime','midday','midnight','morning','morning prayer','night','nightfall','none','nones','noon',
 'noonday','noontide','prime','rush hour','sext','small hours','sundown','sunrise','sunset','sunup','suppertime','terce','tierce','twelve noon','twilight','vespers','zero hour']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the knowledgebase of wordnet. It's an organized database of words, grouped into synonym sets (synsets). These are organized into a hierarchy. For example, there is a high-level synset for time of day which includes words you are looking for: http://wordnetweb.princeton.edu/perl/webwn?o2=&o0=1&o8=1&o1=1&o7=&o5=&o9=&o6=&o3=&o4=&r=1&s=time+of+day&i=1&h=1000#c

You can access wordnet via nltk (alternatively omw or wn packages): *from nltk.corpus import wordnet*.